# How to add resource files to fat jar using vertx:package

Tags: java, vert.x

I am trying to build a fat jar file for my project. It build alright but my config file in resources folder can't be found.

this is my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <vertx.verticle>com.vertx.MainVerticle</vertx.verticle>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <vertx.version>3.4.0</vertx.version>
    <fabric8-vertx-maven-plugin.version>1.0.5</fabric8-vertx-maven-plugin.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-mysql-postgresql-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-web-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${fabric8-vertx-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <redeploy>true</redeploy>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

below is my resource folder structure

[image]

the file which is missing is the config.json. It contains values that are used by my class. However when i run the jar file I get the error 
`java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`

This is how load the file

```
public static JsonObject config() {
    try {
        if (jsonObj != null)
            return jsonObj;

        ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        String jsonStr = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(classloader.getResource("config.json").getPath())));
        return new JsonObject(jsonStr);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new JsonObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you load this file in your code?

Comment: @AlexeySoshin i didn't know how to put it into the comment so i have edited my post

Comment: Why do you try to get it like that? `AbstractVerticle` already has `config()` method that will fetch the file for you.

Comment: I think the point of OP is to include the file into his fat jar, not to get feedback on how he is retrieving the file -- that works fine for his usecase